# get category in posts, php

Tags: php, wordpress

i try to write a simple code for php, which can show date,post autho and category but i can not show category. Where can i add it? this is code:

```
$posted_on = sprintf(
    esc_html_x( 'Posted on111 %s', 'post date',  'sanse' ),
    '<a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">' . $time_string . '</a>'
);

$byline = sprintf(
    esc_html_x( 'by %s', 'post author', 'sanse' ),
    '<span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="' . esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ) . '">' . esc_html( get_the_author() ) . '</a></span>'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside have_posts loop you can use get_the_category() function to display posts' categories.

```
$categories = get_the_category();
if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $categories[0]->term_id ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $categories[0]->name ) . '</a>';
}
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/